# No output on ParametricPlot

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica, physics

I'm solving and plotting the equations of motion for the double pendulum using Mathematica's `NDSolve`.

I've successfully plotted the Angular position using a standard plot. But when I come to use the parametric plot for the position of each mass. I get no errors but simply no plot.

```
eqn1 = 2 th''[t] + Sin[th[t] - ph[t]] (ph'[t])^2 + Cos[th[t] - ph[t]] (ph''[t]) + (2 g/l) Sin[th[t]]
eqn2 = ph''[t] + Sin[th[t] - ph[t]] (th'[t])^2 + Cos[th[t] - ph[t]] (th''[t]) + (g/l) Sin[th[t]]
eqnA = eqn1 /. {g -> 10, l -> 1}
eqnB = eqn2 /. {g -> 10, l -> 1}

sol = NDSolve[{eqnA == 0, eqnB == 0, th[0] == 0.859, th'[0] == 0, ph[0] == 0.437, ph'[0] == 0}, {th, ph}, {t, 0, 10}]
Plot[{th[t], ph[t]} /. sol, {t, 0, 10}]
r1 = {lSin[th[t]] + lSin[ph[t]], -lCos[th[t]] - lCos[ph[t]]} /. {l -> 1, g -> 10}

ParametricPlot[r1 /. sol, {t, 0, 10}]
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
r1 = {lSin[th[t]] + lSin[ph[t]], -lCos[th[t]] - lCos[ph[t]]} /. {l->1, g->10}
```

with

```
r1 = {l*Sin[th[t]] + l*Sin[ph[t]], -l*Cos[th[t]] - l*Cos[ph[t]]} /. {l->1, g->10}
```

and your `ParametricPlot` should appear.

One useful trick you might remember, when any plot doesn't appear you can try replacing the plot with `Table` and see what it shows. Often the table of data provides the needed hint about why the plot isn't appearing.